# Android Play Services Resolution "device not supported"

Tags: android, google-play, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm running my app on android 2.3, I'm using google maps api v2.  I am trying to manage a resolution, all goes well until I'm redirected to the play store.  The play store displays a warning "Your device isn't compatible with this version".

I can't find more information on this. i.e can I get a supported version, which devices does this effect? Is it now not possible to support maps on 2.3?

My resolution code:

```
private boolean checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable () {
        final int connectionStatusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        Log.i("checkGooglePlayServicesAvailable, connectionStatusCode="
                + connectionStatusCode);
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
            return false;
        }
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(ErrorPlayServicesActivity.this,
                "Google Play service available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
        return true;
    }

    void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog (
    final int connectionStatusCode){
        ErrorPlayServicesActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          //  public static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 0;
            private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
            public void run() {
                final Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                        connectionStatusCode, ErrorPlayServicesActivity.this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                if (dialog == null) {
                    Log.e("couldn't get GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog");
                    Toast.makeText(ErrorPlayServicesActivity.this,
                            "incompatible version of Google Play Services",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: do you try this code to run in emulator ??

Comment: Okay, the device was rooted with a custom rom, seemed to have been the issue there.